# How to fix file field button submitting form multiple times

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

The button for file field keeps submitting the form when it should be opening a window to select files to upload. Does anyone have an idea why?

```
= render 'show'
.row
  .col-12
    %ZenForm{ path: zen_support_urls.ticket_path, id: @zendesk_ticket.id, method: :put, :multipart => true, data: { remote: true } }
      %button.fileUpload.btn.btn-default#upload_button{data: {type: "button"}}
        Attach File
        %input.upload#file_input{:name => "attachments[]",  multiple: true, :type => "file"}/
      %ul#filelist
      - @zendesk_ticket.comments.each do | comment |
        = render 'files', comment: comment
      %ZenTextArea#comment{ label: "Comments", placeholder: "Add any comments you think will help us address your issue.", error: @zendesk_ticket.errors&.dig(:comment) }
```

Here is my JavaScript in app.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require select2
//= require ./base
//= require ./tickets
//= require_tree .
```

Here is my CoffeeScript for tickets:

```
$(document).on "ready page:load", () ->
  # this method forwards clicks to the first <a> element in the row
  $.activateRowClick = (selector) ->
    $(selector).click (e) ->
      if !$(e.target).is('a')
        $(this).find('a').click()
    $(selector).css('cursor', 'pointer')

  $.activateRowClick('tr.clickable')
```

Here is my JavaScript for ticketform.js:

```
$(document).on "ready page:load", ->

  $support = new ZenSupport.Form "zs-ticket-form"

  $support.comment = $support.form.find('textarea')
  $support.subject = $("#zs-ticket-form__subject")
  $support.priority = $("#zs-ticket-form__priority")
  # $support.actions = $support.form.find('.support-ticket__action-btns')

  $support.fields =
    inputs: [$support.comment]
    select2: [
      $support.subject, 
      $support.priority
    ]

  $support.subject.select2
    theme: "bootstrap"
    placeholder: "Please select..."
    width: "100%"
    allowClear: true
    tags: true

  $support.priority.select2
    theme: "bootstrap"
    placeholder: "Please select..."
    width: "100%"
    allowClear: true
    tags: false

  # Provide the beforeSend
  $support.beforeSend = ->
    has_subject = $support.subject.val().length
    has_comment = $support.comment.val().length
    placeholder = $support.comment.attr('placeholder')

    required_inputs = $support.form.find(".required:visible")

    inputs_valid = true

    $.each required_inputs, (index, element) ->
      console.log $(element).val().length

      if($(element).val().length == 0)
        $(element).parent().addClass('has-error')
        inputs_valid = false
      else
        $(element).parent().removeClass('has-error')
      return

    if has_subject and has_comment and has_comment isnt placeholder and inputs_valid
      $support.showLoader false
      return true
    else
      $support.comment.parent('.form-group').toggleClass 'has-error', !has_comment
      $support.subject.parent('.form-group').toggleClass 'has-error', !has_subject
      return false
```

Here is my code for uploads.js. This file is not getting called when `tickets` is being called so this code is currently not doing anything and I think that is the problem:

```
$ ->
    files = [];

    $("#upload_button").click ->
        $("#file_input").trigger "click";

    $("#file_input").change (event) -> 
        file = event.target.files[0];
        files.push(file);
        uploadfile files.length - 1, file;

    uploadfile = (index, file) ->
        formData = new FormData();
        formData.append "file", file;
        fileitem = "
            <li class='file-item success'>
                <div class='active'>
                    <span class='remove'>×</span>
                    <span>#{file.name}</span>
                </div>
                <div class='lds-ellipsis'><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
            </li>
        ";
        $('#filelist').append fileitem;
        setRemove();

    setRemove = ->
        $(".remove").unbind();
        $(".remove").click ->
           index = $(@).parent().parent().index();
           files.splice index, 1;
           $('.file-item').eq(index).remove();
```

Comment: Your haml looks good to me. I assume some global javascript in your application may be triggering this.

Comment: @PardeepDhingra i put my javascript up. Whenever ticket and ticketform javascript is loaded upload.js isnt uploaded.